# How to change the cursor in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, cursor

How do I change the cursor to an image I have in the local machine?
I have followed this tutorial for code reference:
http://www.newthinktank.com/2018/07/qt-tutorial-5-paint-app/

Comment: What do you call a _"cursor to an image"_. Please be more explicit and show an example of your issue. Help people to help you.

Comment: I want my mouse pointer to be an image I have, instead of the default arrow.

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also retake the [tour] and reread [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .qrc file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>cursors/my_cursor.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then program this way:

```
QPixmap p = QPixmap(":my_cursor");
QCursor c = QCursor(p, 0, 0);
setCursor(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the class [QCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#QCursor-1), once the mouse is inside the image you can modify its shape by using the function setShape().

Like the documentation says:

> To associate a cursor with a widget, use QWidget::setCursor(). To
>   associate a cursor with all widgets (normally for a short period of
>   time), use QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor().
>
> To set a cursor shape use QCursor::setShape() or use the QCursor
>   constructor which takes the shape as argument, or you can use one of
>   the predefined cursors defined in the Qt::CursorShape enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can change cursor *temprorarily* and on a *stable* basis.

**Stable way means, the cursor is just set as it is.**
Use [`QWidget::setCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#cursor-prop).
Note, the object, where this is applied has to be a QWidget.

**Temporary way overrides the permanent cursor.**
When you do
[`QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(/* your cursor here */));`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setOverrideCursor) you add this cursor to the stack, atop. If several cursors are laid, while popping them, we get them in reverse order.
To pop a cursor we do:
[`QGuiApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#restoreOverrideCursor)

It doesn't really matter for just a single change or a swing to and fro, but this will matter if there's a chance that cursors pile.